# SQL update primary keys and foreign keys at the same time

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database in mysql. Now in one table there is a primary key and in the other tables there are foreign keys. How do I update the primary key and have it update all the foreign keys at the same time? I remember being taught it and it being a word starting with C I think, can't remember. Oh and I don't want to individually update each table one by one.

Thanks for any help given.
Arran

Comment: You cannot update primary key in any of your database table, you will need to delete the record and re-insert into your database.

Comment: @Murtaza This is not even remotely true. [Example Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a2581/880)

Comment: @GarethD - Just executed your fiddle but it did not gave me the updated Id in my select statement  Result was `Record Count: 0; Execution Time: 0ms `

Comment: @Murtaza scroll down further - the Recordd count: 0... is produced by the update statement. There is a further recordset produced by the second select.

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure your foreign keys have the referential triggered action `ON UPDATE CASCADE`.